# Express js modular REST framework

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mean-stack

I am planning to develop only rest api using express js, I looked into lot of boilerplate projects. None of them provide modularity. Modularity I mean all code related to articles module need to be in article folder then I can drag and drop that.

I saw MEAN somewhat close to that but it has client side (angular related) code in that. I need pure rest api framework.

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more specific? In general you are right, you do not need the full MEAN stack, a simple `express` app is enough to build a modular rest api. What is your question?

Comment: @Jonas As express js doesn't provide any best practise to structure your application, I am looking for some boilerplate code. All boilerplate I saw doesn't have modular structure. That means I can't keep all files related to one module in one folder and disable or enable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it doesn't sound like you want to use a MEN stack, I do not see a reason to use MongoDB in your question. You can write modular `express` apps e.g. like this:

Assuming you have three modules in three different folders `moduleA`, `moduleB` and `moduleC`. Each folder contains its respective logic and provides some RESTful routes to the outside world. In `express` you would create one separate `Router` for each module like this:

ModuleA:

```
/* moduleA/routes.js */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

... // add all routes of moduleA

module.exports = router;
```

ModuleB:

```
/* moduleB/routes.js */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

... // add all routes of moduleB

module.exports = router;
```

ModuleC:

```
/* moduleC/routes.js */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

... // add all routes of moduleC

module.exports = router;
```

And then you would have one main `app.js` file in your root folder where you enable and disble the single modules by mounting them into the main `express` app:

```
/* app.js */
var express = require('express');
var moduleA = require('./moduleA/routes');
var moduleB = require('./moduleB/routes');
var moduleC = require('./moduleC/routes');

var app = express();

... // add your main app's middlewares

app.use('/moduleA', moduleA);
app.use('/moduleB', moduleB);
// app.use('/moduleC', moduleC);

app.listen(3000);
```

In this example the modules `moduleA` and `moduleB` are enabled and are reached by the routes `/moduleA/*` and `/moduleB/*` respectively. The module `moduleC` is disabled as we commented it out.

If you have questions please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use a "MEN" stack, which is MongoDB (for backend), Express, and Node.JS.

Here's a tutorial on how to build a project with a "MEN" stack: https://github.com/maslennikov/node-tutorial-men or this one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4